# How to validate JWT from frontend using a JWT Utility on the backend? (React + Springboot)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Ok, so I have a React component that I only want loaded if `JWT` in local storage is valid (meaning token is not expired and it is the correct token). Currently, I am only able to check one of those things, if it is expired or not.

This is the `componentDidMount` function in that component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;

    // validate token
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    AuthService.validateToken()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("step 1");
        if (res == undefined || res == null || !token) {
          this.props.history.push("/login");
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("step 2");

        TicketService.getTickets().then((res) => {
          if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({ tickets: res.data });
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

The `AuthService.validateToken()` looks like this:

```
  // IS token expired?
  validateToken() {
    console.log(" about to try validating");
    return AxiosInstance.get("authenticate")
      .then("did it")
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

And the `AxiosInstance` is just that. I'll share the code to my Axios Instance as well:

```
const AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${getTokenFromLocalStorage()}` },
});

function getTokenFromLocalStorage() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  console.log("the token is -> " + token);
  if (token === null) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return token;
}
```

Finally, the end point looks like this:

```
    // returns the username
    @GetMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> validateHeaderToken() throws Exception {

        String username = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to validate token");
            String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            token = token.split("Bearer ")[1];
            username = jwtTokenUtil.extractUsername(token);

            // TODO : this should eventually use the .validateToken method once I figure out
            // how to pass in UserDetails
            if (!jwtTokenUtil.isTokenExpired(token)) {
                return ResponseEntity.ok(username);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Expired or Invalid Token");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(400).build();
        }

    }
```

So as you can see, I am only checking if the token is expired in the function above ^^. I want to use my JWT Utility to use the `validateToken` that already exists. This is my JWT Utility:

```
  public String extractUsername(String token) {
        // we set the username as the subject when we created the token so we can
        // extract the username from the claim like this
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        // extract the claim that is attached to the token, if any
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    public Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        // create token using the username as subject
        return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        // Expiration is 10 hours from creation
        // subject is username
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SECRET_KEY).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
```

So, all of the useful functions are there in my JWT Utility, but `validateToken()` requires `UserDetails` AND `token`. Where and how do I get the `UserDetails` to pass into the `validateToken` function??

EDIT: the user details are already loaded, when I refresh my page, I can see the user details printed for whoever is logged in, but not sure how to access it from other places.

EDIT: `MyUserDetailsService` looks like this:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeServices employeeServices;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("S is -> " + s);
        Employee employee = employeeServices.getEmployeeByUsername(s);
        System.out.println(employee);
        // if (employee == null) {
        // throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username was not found. Could not log
        // in.");
        // }

        return new User(employee.getUsername(), employee.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

And when I refresh my page, this gets called each time. I can see the `S is ->` printed to my terminal on each page refresh. Is this where I should store User Details in a Cookie?

Comment: Spring has had built in jwt support for 3 years, why are you building custom security? Custom homemade security is bad practice. Why use a security framework if you are going to ignore what the framework offers. Also storing JWTs in local storage is very bad practice. Please read up on OWASP

Comment: I am new to this and was following a tutorial. I now plan on converting things to best practice. Can you please explain or maybe share a link that I can view that will explain which parts would need to be changed to use built in JWT security?

Comment: Use google and find the documentation for spring security and read the JWT chapter.

Comment: if following a tutorial you should post the tutorial in your question. The tutorial is teaching you bad practices, and i suggest you read the official documentation if you want to learn spring security and dont trust poorly written tutorials that provide faulty information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is compare the data in the cookie to the data in `UserDetails`.

Presumably you have the `UserDetails` stored in a session cookie, or at least an ID for the user.  Without knowing exactly how your session cookies are formed, I can't give an exact answer, but here's the gist of it.

Inside your `validateHeaderToken` method, where you have access to the incoming request object, you should either:

1. Extract the user details from the cookies on the incoming request, or
2. Extract the ID from the cookies on the incoming request, and look up the corresponding user details from your database.

then

3. Pass the user details along with the token to your `validateToken` method.

MDN article on cookies in headers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie

Comment: I printed out my cookies and it was empty. I didn't have any. I made an update to my question, could you please review it?

Comment: Well, somehow your user details are visible on the page.  How are they getting there?  It's not totally clear to me _why_ you want to compare what's in a valid token to the logged in username, since that kind of defeats the purpose of a bearer token, but you said you wanted to compare them, so you need to add the user details to the auth request somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'

if(jwtToken){

    const decodedToken = jwtDecode(jwtToken);
    console.log(decodedToken);
    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;      
    console.log(decodedToken.exp < currentTime);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).